# Apply Kirchoff Law to an $LC$ circuit (no battery)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

[image]

In the image above, I understand the current is moving clockise. I was attempting to apply Kirchoff Rule which for an RLC circuit is

[image]

but I wanted to confirm that $V_s$ is zero in this scenario such that I would have the negative signs cancel, that or are they originally positive, taken that $IR=0$. The convention is confusing me.

Comment: If the switch is closed then the potential difference across it $V_s$ is zero as it will offer no voltage drop. The equation becomes $L\ddot{i}+iR+^q/_C=0$.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the current is moving clockise.

That's an easy beginner mistake to make. Don't think about which way a current or voltage goes. In most circuits its going both ways anyway. Just pick a direction (mark it with arrow) and stick with it. If the number that you get is positive, it means it goes with the direction that you picked, if it's negative it goes the other way.

Just make sure that for all passive parts current and voltages go in the same direction, and for sources current and voltage go into opposite ones.

In your case it's fine to count the current positive clockwise (although the other direction would work just as well). Since all your elements are passive you should count the voltages positive in the same direction as the current, so your loop equation simply becomes
$$V_C + V_L + V_S = 0 $$

When the switch is open, the current is zero and so is $V_L$. Hence you get
$$V_C + V_S = 0$$
When you close the switch you get $V_S = 0$ and so the loop becomes.
$$V_C + V_R = 0$$
Pop in the differentials

$$\int i\cdot dt/C + L\cdot di/dt = 0$$
differentiates once
$$i/C + L \cdot d^2i/dt^2 = 0$$
and solve for the initial conditions of $i(t=0) = 0$ and $V_C(t=0) = Q/C$